# How to use USB 3.0 inner cables by color?

Tags: power, usb, cables

I have an USB 3.0 cable I want to use only for powering a basic circuit with 5V and the max current I can get from USB 3.0.

Once cut, I can see these cables :

[image]

I know the red and black are power and ground, white and green are for USB 2.0 data.

According to these links, I can see that the 2 other are said to be SDP/SSTX/SSRX/USB 3.0 signal...

https://www.conec.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2017/09/IP67-USB3.0-Assembly-Instructions-Aug-21-2017.pdf

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/USB-3.0-machine-vision-camera-hardware-design-and-Zhuang/da035ac587250936a1a6606ba05a2a879cc855a6/figure/3

https://www.dhresource.com/0x0/f2/albu/g7/M00/91/E0/rBVaSVsPJeiASxomAAG91UKxjdw068.jpg

But I'm not sure to understand what these are for...

My question is : are the red and black wires the right and only ones for power lines, or are there other cables that manage power ?

Comment: The other cables matter if you're trying to use QC or PD or something, but if you just need 5 V at low current you just need the red and black ones.

Comment: @Hearth:I'd like to use 5V, but not only the 500mA max current of the USB 2.0. If I can drain more, I'd like to. Question edited to explain that.

Comment: @Oliver, note that for anything above 100mA you need to negotiate in some form. For 2A power delivery over USB 2.0, that is a resistance measurement, for 3.0 it can be negotiated over data as well IIRC. I'd use a dedicated IC for that, your request is common enough that these exist.

Comment: @SimonRichter:Can you please explain "that is a resistance measurement" for 2A over USB 2.0 ? And for 3.0, how/with what is the negociation done (any piece of electronic I don't know) ?

Comment: @SimonRichter:There is a point I don't understand, I have a basic 5V LED bar powered by USB (white USB port) with 2 wires and no specific circuit that could manage anything. When connected to any modern USB power bank, it draws, depending on the powerbank, from 1 to 1.7A. I'd like to achieve the same thing, and don't want to open (destroy) the USB port of the LED bar to see how it's done inside.

Comment: Charge-only ports have a resistor with a specific value across the data pins, the value tells the allowed current. This allows a device to distinguish between a computer where it wouldn't be allowed to draw more than 100mA and a powerbank or charger. With a computer port you can request 500mA on USB 2.0, and IIRC USB 3.0 introduces higher current options -- but these can be denied.

Comment: If you only want to use this on a power bank or wall charger, forget about the negotiation, and just make sure you recognize power-only ports correctly. The device will then refuse to work when connected to a computer (bonus points for an LED that says "Please use a power bank"), but it likely wouldn't have worked anyway.